# Entity Framework Core ignoring .Include(..) without .ToList(..) indirectly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

As noted [in "Loading Related Data" from EF Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) we can use `.Include(..)` to Eagerly Load navigation properties from the `DbSet` (or generic `IQueryable<T>` linking back to an EF context).

This means that, given the following models:

```
public class TestEntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TestEntityBId { get; set; }
    public TestEntityB TestEntityB { get; set; }

    public string BProperty { get { return TestEntityB.Property; } }
}

public class TestEntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

.. then code such as the following should work:

```
context.TestEntityAs
    .Include(m => m.TestEntityB)
    .Any(m => m.BProperty == "Hello World");
    /*
     * Note that the below DOES work by using the nav property directly
     * in the query, but that is not always going to be an option for
     * whatever reason. If it's .Included it should be available through
     * INNER JOINing it into the base query before the .Any runs.
     * .Any(m => m.TestEntityB.Property == "Hello World");
     */
```

However it doesn't.

I note that there is a caveat where `.Include()` could be ignored should a query not return the type that is initially requested:

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are ignored. [snip] By default, EF Core will log a warning when include operators are ignored.

I'm not sure how, in the above call to `.Any()` that is relevant. Yes, the query is not returning the original type (it's returning a `bool` of course) but at the same time, the Warning is also not logged to advise that it is being ignored.

My questions here are:

- Is this a usage case that is expected to work? Should I raise a bug in EF Core?
- If it's not expected, *a* workaround is as below (to call `.ToList()`) but that would obviously load everything, to find out if we have anything on a `.Any()` which could easily be a query (and would be as such in EF6). What is a workaround to get this `.Any()` to work on the server side thus not requiring the ToList to put it in memory?

Workaround:

```
context.TestEntityAs
    .Include(m => m.TestEntityB)
    .ToList()
    .Any(m => m.BProperty == "Hello World");
```

Full reproducible sample: https://gist.github.com/rudiv/3aa3e1bb65b86ec78ec6f5620ee236ab

Comment: What is the SQL that is generated for the first query that doesn't work? You shouldn't need to Include anything for this, it should just work.

Comment: @DavidG Indeed I believe it should (as I said), but: `SELECT "m"."Id", "m"."TestEntityBId" FROM "TestEntityAs" AS "m"`. Doing the `.ToList()` correctly evaluates as it does an `INNER JOIN` to TestEntityBs.

Comment: What is the EF Core version? It works as expected on latest with SqlServer.

Comment: @IvanStoev 1.1.1 - Sqlite. See the Gist and if you could, see if it reproduces in SQL Server backend? EDIT: I've corrected the explicit failure here, it's not using the nav property _directly_ that is broken.

Comment: That's the point - it doesn't. I didn't try your model (I could) because I have already very similar.

Comment: @IvanStoev See my update, if you add a property on your model that looks at the nav property, but don't use it directly in the query, you'll note that it's ignored. My key point here is that, regardless of whether it's direct or indirect, surely `.Include()` should be wiring up the underlying query to do an INNER JOIN for mapping?

Comment: I think I saw the  problem in your code - you are using unmapped property `m => m.BProperty`. Just don't do that  - use  `m => m.TestEntityB.Property`instead.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes I'm aware of this. Consider `BProperty` being an interfaced property that could look at different nav properties depending on the underlying type, it's not as simple as using the nav property directly in all queries. Again, if I'm explicitly loading the nav properties, it should be available in the final `.Any()`.

Comment: @RudiVisser: `BProperty` is a calculated property in your case and do not map to a table column, that's why it can't be used to translate expressions into T-SQL etc. Everything you use within the `IQueryable<T>`'s extension methods **must be mappable to a table column**, because it gets translated into the query. EF Core is unaware that `BProperty` points to B Property

Comment: From my experience with EF, I would not use OOP abstractions like interfaces, inheritance, accessors etc. Entities should represent simple data and relationships. And everything should be visible to the queries. That's the key for successfully using EF (Core).

Comment: Anyway, regarding the concrete issue, it duplicates on SqlServer as well. There is a warning that the unmapped property will be evaluated in memory. But `Include` apparemtly is ignored, so NRE. I think you should post it to their issue tracker.

Comment: @IvanStoev: The Include is ignored because it makes no sense in this context imho. a `.Any(...)` query usually translates into something like `SELECT id FROM table WHERE x = "y" LIMIT 1` and the fields/columns aren't validated/mapped at all, because all the any methods needs to know is "Was the result count 0 or greater than 1" and in such cases the relationships aren't required. They are only required when you want to load additional data. I believe that's also the reason why you can configure the warnings (or turn them into errors) during configuration

Comment: @Tseng I think the OP's point (and I should sort of agree) is that since this cannot be translated to SQL, it should be evaluated in memory (EF Core feature, EF6 would simply throw not supported exception), hence the `Include` should be in effect - like if you do `.AsEnumerable().Any(...)` which btw works.

Comment: @Tseng I agree in this case, but in something like `context.TestEntityAs.Include(m => m.TestEntityB).Select(m => m.BProperty)` it would make more sense. But I think it's going to be hard for EF to decide when `Include` is relevant for the end result. I don't think they're going to support this scenario.

Comment: I'm with @GertArnold here, I'm not even sure how you could support a situation like this. EF cannot translate the computed property to a table value under any situation (except perhaps some weird Roslyn madness)

Comment: @DavidG @GertArnold Supporting `.TestB.Property` vs supporting `.BProperty` should be no different in reality - granted perhaps not via a standard property like I have, but by perhaps returning a compiled expression it should be possible... In fact, that sounds like an idea..

Comment: It's very different in reality because EF has no way to know what happens inside the computed property so it can't be converted to an SQL query. An expression might work, but if you're going to be editing the entity, why not just fix the queries instead?

Comment: @DavidG Because my real world example is `get { return Company.Instance.Key; }` and `get { return Instance.Key; }` in some scenarios (and it can get more complex). The key is that it needs to go down to a lower level (off a nav property) and I can load them in via `.Include`, but then it doesn't work as described here. If my `return X.X.X`. could be a compiled query that would be better. I understand it's not a supported scenario but yeah, there has to be some way to handle it in EFC like there is in EF.

Comment: a workaround could be to use a method instead of a getter property. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

by naming convention, it should be worked
you can try using this piece of code to manually configure relations between your models

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestEntityA>()
        .HasOne(x => x.TestEntityB)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.TestEntityBId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is expected but you can use explicit loading for more efficient query as shown below.

2 separate queries, but no need to load all of TestEntityBs

```
// First query
var testEntityAs = context.TestEntityAs.ToList();
var testEntityAsIds = testEntityAs.Select(t => t.Id);

// Second query, can apply filter of Hello World without loading all TestEntityBs
context.TestEntityBs
    .Where(t => testEntityAsIds.Contains(t.Id) && t.Property == "Hello World")
    .Load();

// In memory check
var isAny = testEntityAs.Any(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.BProperty));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data, likely the efficient way to achieve that would be to load a single record:

```
context.TestEntityAs
    .Include(m => m.TestEntityB)
    .Where(m => m.BProperty == "Hello World")
    .FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try  [ForeignKey(nameof(TestEntityBId ))]

```
public class TestEntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TestEntityBId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TestEntityBId ))] public TestEntityB TestEntityB { get; set; }

    public string BProperty { get { return TestEntityB.Property; } }
}

public class TestEntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question but it is kind of a workaround.

change `BProperty` to be a method like `getBProperty`

```cs
public string getBProperty (TestEntityB tb) {  return tb.Property;  }
```

and then write your query like

```cs
context.TestEntityAs
    //.Include(m => m.TestEntityB) --- you don't need include anymore!
    .Any(m => m.getBProperty(m.TestEntityB)) == "Hello World");
```