# SQLite and Entity Framework Core: why include doesn't work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, include, entity-framework-core

I use EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite v1.1.3, VS 2015, make simple WPF application, .Net 4.6 
`People` and `Orders` tables are related as "many-to-many" through `OrdersToPeople` table in my database. I've made dbContext classes using SQLite Tools.
I use this code to check loaded data:

```
var list = myDbContext.People
    .Include(t => t.OrdersToPeople);
foreach (var element in list)
{
    var c = element.OrdersToPeople.Count;
    //c is always 0. Why?
}
```

When i load `OrdersToPeople` or `Orders` tables the same way

```
var list = myDbContext.OrdersToPeople
```

or

```
var list = myDbContext.Orders
```

, i see the data. When i make SQL-query, it returns me correct data.

Why `Include` does not load `OrdersToPeople`?

P.s. The `OrdersToPeople` field is `virtual`.

```
public partial class People
{
    //...fields...
    public virtual ICollection<OrdersToPeople> OrdersToPeople { get; set; }
    public People()
    {
        OrdersToPeople = new HashSet<OrdersToPeople>();
    }
}
public partial class OrdersToPeople
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public long PeopleId { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual People People { get; set; }
    public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post please your method for extracting the data.

Comment: Not enough info to see the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behaviour is expected. Did you try to invoke ToList on your selection?

It looks like EF is ignoring include without ToList:
[Entity Framework Core ignoring .Include(..) without .ToList(..) indirectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541527/entity-framework-core-ignoring-include-without-tolist-indirectly)

```cs
var list = myDbContext.People
    .Include(t => t.OrdersToPeople);
    .ToList();
```